# @Import scss, relative path, angular-cli

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli

I encountered some issues, by importing `*.css` file with `@import` into `.scss`. The `.css` file got some relative path `url('path')` inside and belongs to imported library, so is on `node_modules`.

My **`.component.scss`** looks like that:

```
@import "~libName/dist/icon";
```

And is imported by `.component.ts`, but it doesn't matter at all.

And **`node_modules/libName/dist/icon.css`** has code:

```
src: url("icons/SAP-icons.woff") format("woff");
```

On building it throws **error** that can't resolve files

> `(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:`, because the `icons/icon.woff` which is in `icon.css`
>   can't be found, becasue of wrong relative path.

`angular v.7.3` with CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{}` to reference the top level of the project path

```
@import "{}/node_modules/module-name/stylesheet";
```